# AVAudioPlayerNode - State of playback and start/finish notifications

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I have an `AVAudioPlayerNode` object that is linked with an `AVAudioEngine`. I used the schedule method to load them in the queue. How can I know the state of the playback and when a single file start and finish to play?

This is the code I use for scheduling :

```swift
playerNode.scheduleFile(file, at: audioTime) {
    // Completion
}
```